# How would I classify the decay in this graph?

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, exponential-function, graphing-functions, data-analysis

I am trying to figure out how to characterize the decay of $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ in the graphs below. I think I don't have a solid grasp on what exponential and algebraic decay really mean.

[image: log-log plot]

[image: semi-log plot]

What I think they mean:

A function (or set of data) decays exponentially if $f(x)$ goes to $0$ as some exponential function of $x$. Similarly, the decay is algebraic if $f(x)$ goes to $0$ as a function of some polynomial function of $x$.

Now, despite this, I'm not sure how I would classify the below. Here's what I think:

$f(x)$ obviously displays some sort of "split behaviour". Some of the function values are basically zero, but the rest of them certainly follow some trend. The fact that it's a straight line on the log-log plot makes me think that the decay is not exponential. Does this mean that it's algebraic?

$g(x)$ I'm not quite sure what to make of. It has some concavity on both plots, so I don't know how to interpret that.

$h(x)$ looks to me like a typical case of exponential decay.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Note that your first plot is loglog; power laws $ax^b$ show as linear in this scale, and sums of such things begin to look linear as $x \to \infty$ in this scale. Your second plot is semilogy: exponentials $ab^x$ show as linear in this scale. So the red "line" shows something like f(x) being a power law (though I don't know what the deal is with the lower red dots). The blue in the first image shows that $g$ decays faster than algebraically. The blue in the second image shows that $g$ decays more or less exponentially (seemingly a bit faster in the long run but with some oscillation too).

Comment: (Cont.) As you said, $h$ is definitely exponential.